# Get subscripts of sum of expression and save each summand's subscript separately

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I deal with expressions like

```
A= a_i a_j a_k + a_i a_l a_m+ ...
```

where the a_i notation is shorthand for Subscript["a",i] and all subscripts are integers. In this example each summand has 3 terms but in general it can have an arbitrary length. In the end I want to have something like

```
{{i,j,k},{i,l,m},...}
```

Using

```
A /. Plus -> List
```

I managed to separate the summands into list entries

```
B = {a_i a_j a_k, a_i a_l a_m,...}
```

and by the replacement rule

```
C= B /. {Subscript[a_,n_] :> ToString[n]}

C = {i j k, i l m,...}
```

where I needed the ToString command because otherwise Mathematica evaluates the product  i j k to a number.

I am now looking for a way to get the

```
list={{i,j,k},{i,l,m},...}
```

output where all variables are treated as numbers again, so I can use them later to access their corresponding elements of some other list.

I appreciate any kind of help as I am not so fluent in Mathematica yet.

Comment: how about `A /. Plus|Times -> List /. Subscript[x_, y_]:>y`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[77]
expr = Plus @@ Times @@@ Map[Subscript[a, #]&, Table[RandomSample[Range@9, 3], {5}], {-1}]

TeXForm @ expr
```

> $a_4 a_6 a_7+a_3 a_4 a_8+a_4 a_6 a_8+a_3 a_5 a_9+a_1 a_8 a_9$

```
expr /. Plus | Times -> List /. Subscript -> (#2 &)
```

> {{4, 6, 7}, {3, 4, 8}, {4, 6, 8}, {3, 5, 9}, {1, 8, 9}}

Alternatively,

```
Extract[#, Position[#, Subscript] /. 0 -> 2] & /@ (List @@ expr)
```

> {{4, 6, 7}, {3, 4, 8}, {4, 6, 8}, {3, 5, 9}, {1, 8, 9}}